# In Django 1.6.x how to get data of associated models in views?

Tags: python, ajax, django, associations

After so much googling I did'nt found any relevant solution for getting the associated models data in views.

Things is I am requesting to the server via Ajax and want to fetch the folders and folder creator name(from User model). But it did'nt return me the first_name of the creator.  Here's the code

models.py

```
class UserFolder(models.Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=150)
    is_shared = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py

```
def pagination(obj, request):
    max = request.GET.get('max') if 'max' in request.GET else 1
    paginator = Paginator(obj, max)  # Show 25 contacts per page
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        return paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
        return paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        return ""

def folder_list(request):   #called via ajax
    folders = UserFolder.objects.filter(creator=request.user.id).order_by('-modified_date')
    folders = pagination(folders, request) #for pagination
    folders = json.dumps({}) if not folders else serializers.serialize("json", folders)
    return HttpResponse(folders)
```

I have tried **.select_related('creator')** too but it did'nt work.

In js I am fetching the data like this :

```
$.each(data, function(i, v) {
                        var t = fldrTpl, id = v.pk;
                        v = v.fields
                        t = t.replace(/\{(ID)\}/g, id);
                        t = t.replace(/\{(NAME)\}/g, v.name);
                        t = t.replace(/\{(C_SIZE)\}/g, (v.current_size == null?0:v.current_size));
                        t = t.replace(/\{(C_ID)\}/g, v.creator.first_name); 
                        t = t.replace(/\{(C_DATE)\}/g, v.created_date);
                        $(".my-folder-table").append(t);
                    });
```

**v.creator.first_name** always return undefined.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: shouldn't it be folders = UserFolder.objects.filter(creator=request.user) instead of request.user.id. request.user is an instance of User while .id results in an integer.

Comment: Thanks for your comment But I have tried this as well and this was also not worked. It returns fields of UserFolders only.

Comment: Did you tested first_name entry exist at User model, and give us User model details as well.

Comment: Yes, I have checked in views if I am doing this 

raise Exception(folders[0].creator.first_name) 

Then it returning me the first_name of the user.

Answer (score 1):

You can always create a dictionary of the data you want to use on your client side:

```
def folder_list(request):   #called via ajax
    folders_obj = UserFolder.objects.filter(creator=request.user).select_related('creator').order_by('-modified_date').all()
    folders_dict = [] 
    for folder in folders_obj:
        d = {}
        for k, v in folder.__dict__.items():
            d[k] = str(v)
        d["creator__first_name"] = folder.creator.first_name
        folders_dict.append(d)
    folders = pagination(folders_dict, request) #for pagination
    folders = json.dumps({}) if not folders else serializers.serialize("json", folders)
    return HttpResponse(folders)
```

And in your js:

```
t = t.replace(/\{(C_ID)\}/g, v.creator__first_name);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But still got a error

" update expected at most 1 arguments, got 2 "

Comment: Thanks for quick response but still not fixed "'list' object has no attribute 'add'"

Comment: Yes I meant append ;)

Comment: Thanks its working now, But this is not what I want it still generating the incorrect data which is not parsed via serializers or json.dumps, So my problem is still not resolved, I would really appreciate if you give me any other solution.

Comment: Some model fields are not serializable so you can convert them to string as in my updated answer, or you could mention fields that you need from folder one by one.

Comment: No it did'nt works, its generating the invalid json. Its generating json something like this

{
    'name': 'folder16',
    'creator__first_name': 'arjun'
}{
    'name': 'folder15',
    'creator__first_name': 'arjun'
}

Comment: @ArjunThakur Thats an array of folder objects. Why do you think it's not valid?